# Appending words to sentence

Tags: java

What is the difference in the run-time of the following approaches?

```
public String merge(String[] words, String[] more) {   
  ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();   
  for (String w : words) sentence.add(w);   
  return Arrays.toString(sentence.toArray());    
}
```

Assuming there is no re-sizing of the list above - how does the time complexity compare to the approach below?

```
public String makeSentence(String[] words) {   
StringBuffer sentence = new StringBuffer();   
for (String w : words) sentence.append(w);   
return sentence.toString();   
}
```

Is there any approach that is even better?

Comment: The latter seems cleaner, though you should use StringBuilder (unless you require thread safety)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The first approach doesn't actually merge anything, and ignores the "more" parameter. Are you missing a step in your examples here? The first example is doing some wasted work, converting an array to an ArrayList and then back to an array again (toArray() creates a copy of the data in the list). The actual string concatenating work is more-or-less similar between Arrays.toString and the second example, although it looks like Arrays.toString uses the non-synchronized StringBuilder internally rather than StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference is that `Arrays.toString()` might want to return you a backet-enclosed, comma-separated list of the words, whereas using a StringBuffer will return you exactly the what you put into it.  Try it and see.  The issue of time complexity becomes moot when the results of one approach or the other might not even be what you wanted.